# iOS: How to get the identifier of an event, which was created via a call to EKEventEditViewController

Tags: ios, events, calendar, reminders

In my app, the user can create events. This is achieved by presenting the user the UI of iOS for creating an event:

```
    - (IBAction)addTermin:(id)sender
    {
        // Create an instance of EKEventEditViewController
    EKEventEditViewController *addController = [[EKEventEditViewController alloc] init];

    // Set addController's event store to the current event store
    addController.eventStore = self.eventStore;
        addController.editViewDelegate = self;
        [self presentViewController:addController animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
```

So, I implement the delegate method:

```
    - (void)eventEditViewController:(EKEventEditViewController *)controller
      didCompleteWithAction:(EKEventEditViewAction)action
   { 
        MRHomeViewController * __weak weakSelf = self;
    // Dismiss the modal view controller
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^
     {
         if (action != EKEventEditViewActionCanceled)
         {
             dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                 // Re-fetch all events happening in the next 24 hours
                 weakSelf.eventsList = [self fetchEvents];
                 // Update the UI with the above events
                 [weakSelf.termineTableView reloadData];
             });
         }
     }];
}
```

So, later I want to retrieve the events a user has created. I was thinking , that somewhere, somehow in the delegate method, I can obtain a reference to the new created event?

Or is there another way to later fetch only events created by the user?

Answer (score 1):

To make this work, you need to first create a new EKEvent, keep a reference to it, and pass it into your EKEventEditViewController:

```
    self.newEvent = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:self.eventStore];
    addController.event = newEvent;
```

In the delegate method, check for `EKEventEditViewActionSaved` and then consult `self.newEvent` to find what you need about the event. If you want to maintain a longer term reference to the event, you can store the `eventIdentifier` or other fields for later lookup.